# Not adding parameters to stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is the signature of my stored procedure:

```
Create Procedure sp_Member_Account_Select_By_User_And_Membership_Year
(
    @Username varchar(150),
   @Membership_Year varchar(10)
)
AS
```

The code in asp.net c#

```
 command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar,150).Value = vUsername;
 command.Parameters.Add("@Membership_Year", SqlDbType.VarChar,10).Value = "2014";

 SqlDataReader dr;
 dr = command.ExecuteReader();
```

The error message:

> Procedure or function
>   'sp_Member_Account_Select_By_User_And_Membership_Year' expects
>   parameter '@Username', which was not supplied.

I have tried different ways of adding parameters, including `Addwithvalue`, but with no success. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide your full c# code related to this stored procedure call?

Comment: Maybe your vUsername is null? Try inserting some string manually instead of vUsername variable just to check if that's not the problem

Comment: Did you set the command type to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Some how I removed the commandtype, good catch. man do i feel bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you obviously add the parameter to the command, there are two more things that can cause this exception:

1. Set the command type to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`:

   ```
   command.ComandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   ```
2. Set the user name parameter to `DBNull.Value` if `vUsername` is null:

   ```
   command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar,150).Value = vUsername ?? DBNull.Value;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Could `vUsername` be null?  When you need to pass a null to a stored procedure, you need to pass the constant `DBNull.Value` rather than `null`.

Something like

```
 command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar,150).Value = 
      (vUsername == null) ? DbNull.Value : (object) vUsername;
```